# Make bot disconnect from all voice channels in all guilds? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I made a discord bot that disconnects from a voice-channel whenever it finds itself alone in a call. This is how I do it: (note, I am using cogs)

```py
@commands.Cog.listener("on_voice_state_update")
  async def voiceStateUpdate(self, member, before, after):
    voiceClient = discord.utils.get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild = member.guild) # Bot "voice_client"

    if voiceClient.channel != None:
      if len(voiceClient.channel.members) == 1:
        await voiceClient.disconnect() # Disconnect
```

This works very well. But, if I forget to leave the call when I *restart* my code, I stay in the channel with my bot as it reboots (as expected). The problem arrives when I disconnect myself from the call. The bot stays in it, only outputting this error: `(line 37, if voiceClient.channel != None:) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'`

Maybe this is because it doesn't know it's still in the channel?
I'm so confused... Thanks for your time. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the voice channel much easier. Also, you need to request the event differently, even though your `("on_voice_state_update")` is correct.

If the bot restarts, it leaves all voice channels immediately or after a few seconds/minutes, so you don't need to worry about that.

**Have a look at the following event:**

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):
    voice_state = member.guild.voice_client # Get the member in the channel
    if voice_state is not None and len(voice_state.channel.members) == 1: # If bot is alone
        await voice_state.disconnect() # Disconnect
```

Note that you have to enable the `members` Intent to get the `len` of `channel.members`. You can do that in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and need to "import" the Intent(s) into your code.

Comment: Ok, so I just need to wait for the bot to leave. Thanks for the tips also! :)

Comment: @DoudGeorges Yes, that is correct. You can of course code a function for it to leave the voice channels when you restart your code, but I don't know if that will do any good. If you restart the bot/code you can't interact with the bot in the voice channel for the time being.